# callback function passed to setInterval is not being called when used in a loop

Tags: javascript

I keep trying to post a question and it keeps getting closed as a duplicate, the last time it was because I forgot to add some code. However, with a little more testing I discovered that the problem is not what I initially thought it was. Here is my code:

```
class GameTimer {
    construtor() {
        this.interval = undefined;
        this.time = 0;              // seconds
    }

    start(seconds) {        
        this.time = seconds;
        this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    tick() {
        this.time--;
        // for testing
        console.log(this.time);
    }

    getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    reset() {
        this.time = 0;
    }
}

// Test
var gameTimer = new GameTimer();

var currentTime = 10;
gameTimer.start(currentTime );

while (gameTimer.getTime() > 0) {
   if (gameTimer.getTime() != currentTime) {
      console.log(gameTimer.getTime());
      currentTime = gameTimer.getTime();
   }
   // This is here only to see if I am going into the loop
   console.log("In loop: " + gameTimer.getTime());
}
```

At first, I thought tick was not getting called because I was getting stuck in the loop. In my original code I did not have the `.bind(this)` on with `this.tick` in the class to `setInterval`. I added that and had the same problem. I tried to post that but was kicked out again because I forgot to add it to the code the I copied into the question (I copied the old code instead of the new). Anyway, with this change it still does not work. I placed `console.log(this.time)` and the time was never output, again making me think that `tick` was not getting called. However, just to see what would happen, I commented out the while loop and sure enough `tick` is getting called. So even though there was a problem with the binding, which I appreciate those who pointed this out, now there seems to be another problem. Why will it not work inside the loop?

Comment: Your `while` is blocking; it's consuming all resources, the `setInterval` callback never gets a chance to run. Don't make blocking loops, maybe put a 20ms delay between each iteration?

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance for the information. I am just learning javascript so I really appreciate the help. Is there anyway in javascript to run the timer on it's own thread or is that out of the scope of the language?

Comment: You *could* run it on its own thread, like with a web worker, but it would still be consuming massive amounts of resources and would never be able to finish. Better never to consume massive amounts of resources unless you actually need them.